# redirection if multiple conditions

Tags: php, redirect

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (strpos($referrer, "bonaca.net46.net") === FALSE
    || !($_POST['pass'] == 1405 || $_POST['pass'] == 999)
{
    header('Location: index.php');
};
?>
```

**What I need:**

If user comes from another page than `bonaca...` OR he typed wrong pass (correct pass are 1405 or 999) he should be redirected.

**What I got:**

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in... on line 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a paranthesis for your if statement .. here

```
1405 || $_POST['pass'] == 999))
                              ^ //<---- Add like this
```

and don't need a semicolon here

```
  header('Location: index.php');
}; //<---- Remove that
```

Comment: Thanks to all. Solved

Answer (score 1):

One of your conditions is outside the if statement, try:

```
if ((strpos($referrer, "bonaca.net46.net") === FALSE
    || !($_POST['pass'] == 1405 || $_POST['pass'] == 999))
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss if condition `)`.Try this code .

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (strpos($referrer, "bonaca.net46.net") === FALSE
    || !($_POST['pass'] == 1405 || $_POST['pass'] == 999))
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this code

<?php
  $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
      if (strpos($referrer, "bonaca.net46.net") === FALSE
          || !($_POST['pass'] == 1405 || $_POST['pass'] == 999)){
        header('Location: index.php');
     }
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

   $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (strpos($referrer, "bonaca.net46.net") === FALSE
        || !($_POST['pass'] == 1405 || $_POST['pass'] == 999))
    {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

try with this.